# JQuery simple dialog box

Tags: php, jquery

```
<link href="simpledialog.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="simpledialog.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function () {
$('.simpledialog').simpleDialog();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.simpledialog').simpleDialog({
opacity: 0.3,
duration: 500,
title: 'Simple Dialog',
open: function (event) {
  console.log('open!');
},
close: function (event, target) {
  console.log('close!');
}
});
});
```

```
$strLink = "<a href='viewTicket.php?id={$row['id']}' class='simpledialog'>$strName</a>";



<a href="#" rel="dialog_content" class="simpledialog">show dialog!</a>

<!-- content -->
<div id="dialog_content" style="display:none;">
<h3>DEMO</h3>
<p>This is a demonstration of jQuery SimpleDialog.</p>
<a href="#" class="close">close</a>
</div>

echo "<td>" . $strLink . "</td>";
```

when I click on the link it is not triggering the jquery

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors. Also you defined it twice. Once with options and one without. Make sure the javascript is being loaded (again, just check if there are any errors).

Comment: may need to move this over to chat to debug it some more

Answer (score 0):

Its better just make some div with `position:absolute` and just show it then you need it.

```
function showDialog() { $('#box').fadeIn(250); $('#box').fadeTo(0.5); }
function hideDialog() { $('#box').fadeOut(250); }
```

You can call it so: Open

And CSS if you need it:

```
#box {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100;
   left: 100;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thats fine and all, but he also has the ajax example, so i can only assume he wants to load something via ajax as well. The other thing with this is positioning, you probably want it centered whether you are scrolled left or right, up or down.

Comment: Well, in basic you can add much more functionality. Basicly, I prefere function calling with this, rather then event adding. Its easear to know where and how it gonna be called. And esear to debug.

Comment: thanks guys! I dont think the positioning is the problem just now as I cant get it to appear on screen?

Comment: @user im pretty sure you have an error. My best guess is the javascript isn't loading. Maybe it's not in the right folder. I can't say.

Comment: As i wrote in my answer, make a div with gaven params, and write that JS code. Then call it with onClick="func()". It will work.

Comment: iv done some debugging by ding an alert when the DOM is loaded and it appears i think its this line        $strLink = "<a href='viewTicket.php?id={$row['id']}' class='simpledialog'>$strName</a>";

Comment: @Ernestas Why use jquery when you are just going to add a function to onclick. You should try to keep your HTML separated from your script. He should be using an event handler to take care of this.

Comment: it's complaining about double quotes around the onclick $strLink = "<a href='viewTicket.php?id={$row['id']}' onclick='showDialog()'>$strName</a>";

Comment: @user please go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript, i can help you debug it more there.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the obvious question: have you included jQuery?  As a jQuery extension, simpleDialog depends on jQuery to work.
   Just by fixing this would make a dialog display onclick, althouth the dialog itself is broken, which brings us to...
2. Secondary, as you can see with the example, simpleDialog works with links.  At this moment (v0.1.1) calling it twice on the same link twice seems to be a no-no.  So make two links and make your functions call simpleDialog only once on each link.
3. Finally, in case you still have problem, since this is a client-side issue only client-side code matters here.  Make sure your php is producing the correct html.  And check that the css and js actually loads (in the correct location etc.). Below is a complete outputted html that works for me:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <link href="css/jquery.simpledialog.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'> </script>
  <script src="js/jquery.simpledialog.js" ></script>
</head><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.simpledialog1').simpleDialog(); // Default usage
  });
  $(document).ready(function () { // Usage with more parameters
    $('.simpledialog2').simpleDialog({
      opacity: 0.7, // Modified parameter to make it different from default
      duration: 1000,
      title: 'Simple Dialog',
      open: function (event) {
        console.log('open!');
      },
      close: function (event, target) {
        console.log('close!');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<a href="#" rel="dialog_content" class="simpledialog1">show default dialog!</a>
<a href="#" rel="dialog_content" class="simpledialog2">show slower dialog!</a>

<!-- content -->
<div id="dialog_content" style="display:none;">
  <h3>DEMO</h3>
  <p>This is a demonstration of jQuery SimpleDialog.</p>
  <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
</div>

</body></html>
```